# Windows virtual keyboard is not showing when input is focused

Tags: javascript, windows, win-universal-app, winjs, windows-10-universal

Windows Virtual keyboard is not showing when app is running in touch mode (tablet device/simulator) and I'm manually triggering `focus()` on input. Instead keyboard shows when tapping anywhere on body (meaning that input is focused). Hoverer when running application as a regular desktop app with mouse input (instead of touch) - everything works well.

So the question is how to avoid such behaviour or at least how to manually display virtual keyboard when input is focused?

I'm using `WinJS.4.0 4.0.0.winjs.2015.6.9`.

Sample code to replicate the issue:

`default.html:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App1</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="WinJS/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="WinJS/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="WinJS/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- App1 references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body class="win-type-body">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="text-holder">
            Input value will be displayed here
        </div>
        <div id="input-holder">
            <form id="form">
                <input id="input" value="" type="number"></input>
            </form>
       </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`default.js`

```
(function () {
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    var textHolder = document.getElementById('text-holder');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e && e.preventDefault();

        textHolder.innerText = input.value;
        input.value = "";
        input.blur();
    });

    textHolder.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        input.focus();
    });
})();
```

`default.css:`

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#text-holder {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #191A15;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Visual guidance:

`Step 1:`

[image: Step 1]

`Step 2:`

[image: Step 2]

Thanks for your interest, hope this problem is solvable.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known OS issue with winjs/uwp app running on a W10 (build 10.240). It has been fixed with W10 TH2 (build 10.586) as mentionned in the following MSDN [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/951d90a5-0f26-4fb4-ae4f-84578507ce34/touch-keyboard-wont-be-activated-within-javascript-universal-app-in-tablet-mode?forum=wpdevelop)